# how to validate dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i have a select input which upon selecting a value, is supposed to generate another set of input according the value initially selected. The problem Im having is with the validation. Validation works fine if i focus on each particular input individually. What i need is a way to validate all input fields at once. Now i already have a function for that called validateAllInputs() which works on another page i worked on although the input fields on that page were static in nature. When i use the same code this page however i keep getting an error "*_this.$refs[f].validate is not a function*"

this is my html code.

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-content>
            <v-container grid-list-md>
                <div class="title grey--text">CASE</div>
                <div class="display-2" style="font-family: Oswald;">RECORD OF CASES CLOSED</div>

                <p>&nbsp;</p>

                <v-snackbar
                        :timeout="timeout"
                        :top="y === 'top'"
                        :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
                        :right="x === 'right'"
                        :left="x === 'left'"
                        :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
                        :vertical="mode === 'vertical'"
                        v-model="snackbar"
                >
                    Saved
                    <v-btn flat color="pink" @click.native="snackbar = false">Close</v-btn>
                </v-snackbar>

                <v-card>
                    <v-card-text>

                        <v-layout>
                            <v-flex xs1 class="text-xs-center pt-4">
                                <v-icon color="blue-grey lighten-2">label</v-icon>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs4>
                                <v-menu
                                        lazy
                                        :close-on-content-click="false"
                                        v-model="menu01"
                                        transition="scale-transition"
                                        offset-y
                                        full-width
                                        :nudge-right="40"
                                        max-width="290px"
                                        min-width="290px"
                                >
                                    <v-text-field
                                            slot="activator"
                                            label="Case Closing Date"
                                            v-model="date02"
                                            append-icon="event"
                                            readonly
                                    ></v-text-field>
                                    <v-date-picker
                                            v-model="date02"
                                            no-title
                                            scrollable
                                            actions
                                    >
                                        <template scope="{ save, cancel }">
                                            <v-card-actions>
                                                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                                <v-btn flat color="blue" @click="cancel">Cancel</v-btn>
                                                <v-btn flat color="blue" @click="save">OK</v-btn>
                                            </v-card-actions>
                                        </template>
                                    </v-date-picker>
                                </v-menu>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs6>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs1 class="text-xs-center pt-4">
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>

                        <v-layout>
                            <v-flex xs1 class="text-xs-center pt-4">
                                <v-icon color="blue-grey lighten-2">label</v-icon>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs4>
                                <v-select label="How Many Cases Closed?" :items="counter_1_to_20" v-model="countCases" autocomplete></v-select>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>

                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>

                <template v-if="countCases != null">
                    <br />
                    <v-card v-for="i in countCases" ref="form">
                            <v-card-text>
                                <v-layout>
                                    <!-- <v-flex xs1 class="text-xs-center pt-4">
                                        <v-icon color="blue-grey lighten-2">label</v-icon>
                                    </v-flex> -->
                                    <v-flex xs1 class="text-xs-center pt-2">
                                        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" fab dark small class="elevation-0" style="z-index: 0;">{{i}}</v-btn>
                                    </v-flex>
                                    <v-flex xs10>
                                        <v-layout>
                                            <v-flex xs12>
                                                <v-text-field name="caseTitle"  ref="caseTitle" v-model="data.caseTitle[i-1]" :rules="[rules.required]" label="Case Title"></v-text-field>
                                            </v-flex>
                                        </v-layout>

                                        <v-layout>
                                            <v-flex xs1 class="text-xs-center pt-4">
                                                <v-icon color="blue-grey lighten-2">trending_flat</v-icon>
                                            </v-flex>
                                            <v-flex xs6>
                                                <v-text-field name="caseRefNumber" ref="caseRefNumber" v-model="data.caseRefNumber[i-1]" :rules="[rules.required]" label="Case Ref Number"></v-text-field>
                                            </v-flex>
                                        </v-layout>

                                        <v-layout>
                                            <v-flex xs1 class="text-xs-center pt-4">
                                                <v-icon color="blue-grey lighten-2">trending_flat</v-icon>
                                            </v-flex>
                                            <v-flex xs6>
                                                <v-select name="validityPeriod" ref="validityPeriod" v-model="data.validityPeriod[i-1]" :rules="[rules.required]" label="Validity Period" :items="optionsValidityPeriod"></v-select>
                                            </v-flex>
                                        </v-layout>

                                        <v-layout>
                                            <v-flex xs1 class="text-xs-center pt-4">
                                                <v-icon color="blue-grey lighten-2">trending_flat</v-icon>
                                            </v-flex>
                                            <v-flex xs6>
                                                <!-- <v-select label="Officer I/C for Tender"></v-select> -->
                                                <v-flex xs12>
                                                    <v-select
                                                            name="officerIC"
                                                            label="Officer I/C for Case"
                                                            v-bind:items="optionsOfficers"
                                                            item-text="name"
                                                            item-value="name"
                                                            max-height="auto"
                                                            autocomplete
                                                            :rules="[rules.required]"
                                                            ref="officerIC"
                                                            v-model="data.officerIC[i-1]"
                                                    >
                                                        <template slot="item" scope="data">
                                                            <template v-if="typeof data.item !== 'object'">
                                                                <v-list-tile-content v-text="data.item"></v-list-tile-content>
                                                            </template>
                                                            <template v-else>
                                                                <v-list-tile-content>
                                                                    <v-list-tile-title v-html="data.item.name"></v-list-tile-title>
                                                                    <v-list-tile-sub-title v-html="data.item.dept"></v-list-tile-sub-title>
                                                                </v-list-tile-content>
                                                            </template>
                                                        </template>
                                                    </v-select>
                                                </v-flex>
                                            </v-flex>
                                        </v-layout>
                                        <br/>
                                    </v-flex>
                                </v-layout>
                            </v-card-text>
                    </v-card>
                    <br />

                    <v-card class="blue-grey darken-2 white--text" dark>
                        <v-card-text>

                            <br /><br />

                            <v-layout>
                                <v-flex xs10>
                                    <v-btn color="orange" @click="validateAllInputs()">Add Case</v-btn>
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>

                        </v-card-text>
                    </v-card>

                </template>

            </v-container>

        </v-content>

        <br /><br />

    </v-app>
</div>
```

And this is my script

```
 export default({
data () {
  return {
    drawer: null,
    items: [
      { title: 'Home', icon: 'dashboard', url: 'tt.html' },
      { title: 'About', icon: 'question_answer', url: 'tt.html' },
    ],
    e1: 0,

    snackbar: false,
    y: 'top',
    x: 'middle',
    mode: '',
    timeout: 1600,
    text: 'Saved',

    data: {
      caseTitle: [],
      caseRefNumber: [],
      validityPeriod: [],
      officerIC: [],
    },

    date02: null,
    menu01: null,

    countCases: null,

    formHasErrors: false,


    rules: {
      required: value => !!value || 'Required.',
    },

    counter_1_to_20: [
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    ],

    optionsValidityPeriod: [
      '90 days', '120 days',
    ],
    optionsOfficers: [
      {
        header: 'Department 1',
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        dept: 'Senior Detective',
      },
      {
        name: 'Smith',
        dept: 'Junior Detective',
      },
      {
        divider: true,
      },
      {
        header: 'Department 2',
      },
      {
        name: 'Mary',
        dept: 'Senior Detective',
      },
    ],
  }
},
computed: {
  form() {
    return {
      officerIC: this.data.officerIC,
      caseTitle: this.data.caseTitle,
      caseRefNumber: this.data.caseRefNumber,
      validityPeriod: this.data.validityPeriod,
    };
  },
},
methods: {
  validateAllInputs() {
    this.formHasErrors = false;
    Object.keys(this.form).forEach(f => {
      if (this.$refs[f].validate(true) === false) {
        this.formHasErrors = true;
        this.$refs[f].validate(true);
        this.text = 'Please rectify errors before proceeding.';
        this.snackbar = true;
      }
    });

    if (this.formHasErrors === false) {
      this.text = 'Saved';
      this.snackbar = true;
    }
  },
}
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the inputs you want to validate inside a `v-form`, then you can just call `this.$refs.form.validate()`

https://vuetifyjs.com/components/forms#example-2

The v-form will handle the dynamically created inputs for you, and they will not be included in the validation if they don't exist.

There is a basic example of this in the PR where I improved that functionality:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/1581
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzRKEW?editors=1010

Comment: I don't like this solution, because if you have 60 fields with validation, you have to wrap all of them with forms just to properly validate dynamically generated fields. Or to trigger validation at will. I wish there was a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! i was searching for this for a long time, mr. life saver.

Comment: @Janpan you can call `validate(true)` on an individual input. It wasn't working for the OP because they have `<v-card v-for="i in countCases"`, so `this.$refs[f]` is itself an array too.

Comment: @Janpan what the OP is saying is that you can wrap the generated fields with a `v-form` component, but you're not obliged to have one `v-form` for each component to validate. You don't need the `v-form` to be one level up of the component, it can be even the root component. If this is the case, then every input el. will be checked. Hope that it helped. (vuetify suggests to check vee-validate & vuelidate - maybe they're more flexible)